# ng-repeat JSON AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was woundering how i can access JSON that has dynamic names:

AngularJS http-get:

```
.then(function (response) {
                    $scope.GTMcontainersAccount = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.GTMcontainersAccount);
```

Response JSON:

```
{
    "Account2": [{
        "accountId": "*******",
        "containerId": "*******",
        "name": "Container23"
    }, {
        "accountId": "*******",
        "containerId": "*******",
        "name": "Container2"
    }],
    "Account 1": [{
        "accountId": "*******",
        "containerId": "*******",
        "name": "Container1"
    }]
}
```

My goal here is to use ng-repeat in a table to show like this:

```
AccountName | AccountId | containerId | name
  Account2  |  *******  |   *******   | Container23
  Account2  |  *******  |   *******   | Container2
  Account1  |  *******  |   *******   | Container1
```

How can use the controller to output something like this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like to this

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>AccountName</th>
    <th>AccountId</th>
    <th>containerId</th>
       <th>name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="(k,v) in data">
  <tr ng-repeat="(k1,v1) in v">
    <td>{{k}}</td>
    <td >{{v1.accountId}}</td>
    <td >{{v1.containerId}}</td>
    <td >{{v1.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Awsome!! Worked like Charm. Thanks @Hadi